# Optional number of parallel flows in an activity diagram UML 2.0

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have a system that starts a undecided number of similar processes (P) at different times, before terminating its activity.  Some of these processes will overlap and some will end before others.
How do I indicate an undecided number of processes in an activity diagram like this:

```
            O
____________|_____________
     |             |
    (P)           (P)
     |             |
_____|_____________|______
            |
            O
```

O: start/end,
(P): process,
*_*_: and-split/join

Here are only two processes, but I need lots of them and without writing them all out explicitly.

Comment: How will you know the number of launched processes in the parallel flow? Is it related to a number of instance? A signal reception?

Comment: I don't know how many processes will be launched.  I want to leave it open.  I'm modeling an event that consists of these processes (or mini events) but I don't want to constrain the model to a specific number of processes.  Is it then more proper to just model the process (P) and describe in text that it will be started an undecided number of times and at different moments in time?

Comment: Of course a description is better than nothing, but what I would prefer a model which says that you will have 0..* launched processes for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the solution I ended up with.  An expansion region in parallel mode.
The text is in swedish but the relevant one is self explanatory.  Expansion regions are described in detail in section 6 [here](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2005_05/column4/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is to create an activity partition, which will refer to a property (having a 0..* cardinality), and containing our process but I am not 100% sure this is what you mean...

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure either, maybe.  I haven't seen heard of partitions but it looks kind of similar to the accepted solution I arrived at and posted.  But I'm not exactly sure how to interpret it.